# How to create a new index array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have an array toolList

```
toolList = [{
      tbl_gaveta_NUMERO: '3',
      tbl_gaveta_DESCRIPCION: 'GAVETA CLORO',
      tbl_herramienta_FECHA: '2021-11-02',
      tbl_herramienta_NOMBRE: 'EXACTO',
      tbl_herramienta_CODIGO: '354']}
```

How to create another index to add a new variable called cantidad? As an example, the cantidad variable to be assigned to cantidad index.

```
toolList = [{
      tbl_gaveta_NUMERO: '3',
      tbl_gaveta_DESCRIPCION: 'GAVETA CLORO',
      tbl_herramienta_FECHA: '2021-11-02',
      tbl_herramienta_NOMBRE: 'EXACTO',
      tbl_herramienta_CODIGO: '354',
      cantidad: cantidad]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new item with the index `'cantidad'` and value of the variable `cantidad` to your associative array using JavaScript method [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
let cantidad = 'test';

toolList.push({'cantidad': cantidad});
```

Comment: Thank you so much but it does not work. I don't know why.

Comment: @Darwin Quiñones Could you provide more infos or code so that we could reproduce, what isnt working?

Answer (score 1):

```
let cantidad
toolList[0]["cantidad"] = cantidad
```

Answer (score 1):

When the variable name matches key name of the object, you can use ES6 syntax like that:

```
const cantidad = 'cantidad'
toolList.push({ cantidad })
```

[MDN docs of the push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)